# Text overlaps with DeclareCaptionListFormat in caption package

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I would like point out something that I think is an issue.
When I try to create a listoffigures, I prefer to see "Figure 1.1 - Test caption" rather than "1.1 Test caption". I used the **\DeclareCaptionListFormat** option but it gives me something weird : **the text overlaps**. Have you got an idea to solve that ? Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, dvipsnames]{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Accentuation automatique
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Pages vierges inutiles
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

% Légendes : paramètres
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figureformat}{Figure~#1~--~#2}
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figureformat, font={bf}, skip=5pt}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\captionof{figure}{Test caption}
Let's do it again :
\captionof{figure}{This is another test caption}
And again, just for fun :
\captionof{figure}{Guess what kind of caption this is ?}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Try to add `\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\quad}` in document preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the my comment:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, dvipsnames]{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Accentuation automatique

% Pages vierges inutiles
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

% Légendes : paramètres
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figureformat}{Figure#1~--~#2}     % <---
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figureformat, font={bf}, skip=5pt}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\quad}                      % <===

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\captionof{figure}{Test caption}
Let's do it again :
\captionof{figure}{This is another test caption}
And again, just for fun :
\captionof{figure}{Guess what kind of caption this is ?}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Apparently OP is faced with two problems:

- how to make space in LoF for figure label
- how to redefine `labelsep` (what I overlooked in the first version of answer).

Solution for both problem is simple. Instead of

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figureformat}{Figure#1~--~#2}     % <---
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figureformat, font={bf}, skip=5pt}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\quad}                      % <===
```

in preamble of above MWE should be:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figureformat}{Figure #1#2 --}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=5pt, font=bf, labelsep=endash,% <---
                      listformat=figureformat}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\ }                      % <---
```

Considered above, the MWE will produce the following result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I am looking for. Just, how can I add a separator between number and text such as `--` or `:`

Comment: Yes of course ^^

Comment: Do you know the answer then?

Comment: @Dorian, what answer?  Where is the question? I already answer on your question. If you have new one, please ask it as question, or if you have some minor problem so far not addressed in your question, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Jan 13 at 9:52 : "Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I am looking for. Just, how can I add a separator between number and text such as `--` or `:`"

Comment: Because your answer gives me "Figure - 1.1 Test caption" and what I am looking for is something like "Figure 1.1 - Test caption". This is exactly what I asked in my question so... In fact ... You don't really answer my question...

Comment: @Dorian, how then I should understand your first comment? To be fer, my answer solve half of your problems (as I see now), other half is solved (hopefully) in edit answer.